# Run exe from vbs error

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to run an executable from a VBScript. Tried this:

```
oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
oShell.ShellExecute("cmd.exe", , , "runas", 1)
oShell.Run("File.exe")
```

However, it gives me sub error on the second line. Where did I do mistake?

Comment: What exactly is the error you get?

Comment: Every line in your script is wrong. Maybe you should start with describing what exactly you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to run File.exe from vbs file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you want to execute file.exe with elevated privileges and keep the window open.

VBScript:

```
set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
oShell.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/K file.exe", "", "runas", 1
```

Note that `runas` verb is undocumented.

PowerShell:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "cmd.exe" -ArgumentList @("/K", "file.exe") -Verb "runas"
```

Comment: Thanks, it works but prompts window asking to allow. Possible to allow it automatically ?

Comment: @user198989 Configure UAC to allow elevation without prompting (via `secpol.msc`).

Comment: The verb isn't *exactly* undocumented. While it's not listed as one of the canonical verbs, the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776886%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says *"The verbs available for an object are essentially the items that you find on an object's shortcut menu"*, i.e. the subkeys of `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\{object name|class ID}\shell`.

Comment: Could you please explain a little bit more Ansgar ?

Comment: @user198989 Start `secpol.msc` and go to *Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options*. Change the setting *User Account Control: Behavior of the elevation prompt for administrators in Admin Approval Mode* to *Elevate without prompting*. Reboot the computer.